# In a quiver plot with ShowArrowHead = 'off', how do I keep the arrowhead from displaying in the legend as well?

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure

When plotting with quiver() and setting the 'ShowArrowHead' property to 'off', the arrowheads aren't shown in the plot (as expected). However, the legend entry still shows an arrowhead.

I would expect the legend for this code block to not show an arrowhead.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-pi:pi/8:pi,-pi:pi/8:pi);
U = sin(Y);
V = cos(X);

q = quiver(X,Y,U,V);
q.ShowArrowHead = 'off';
q.Marker = '.';
legend()
```

[Quiver plot showing the marker at the base of the line (as expected), but an arrowhead as well which should not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrnKe.png)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see an obvious solution to this. I might be able to come up with a workaround but this seems like it may be a bug/oversight that would be best reported to The Mathworks: [http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports).